Bloc Turns Null After Initializing Subscribed Cubits
I have a bloc called WorkItemDetailsBloc, which is subscribed to two cubits: AttachmentsCubit and FollowersCubit. I use these subscriptions to be able to update the UI when the user updates either attachments or followers (e.g., when the user updates the number of followers in the FollowersCubit, I dispatch an event which updates the work item and its followers number).
I am able to dispatch the event, however, after I initialize either FollowersCubit or AttachmentsCubit, WorkItemDetailsCubit becomes null, that is, all the properties that I have in the state become null. I think this started to happen when I transitioned from using Navigator to go_router because it was working fine before that.
Updating WorkItemDetails screen whose state is managed by WorkItemDetailsBloc via events which are not triggered by these subscriptions works just fine.
What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.
Btw, you can find all the relevant code snippets below.
Navigation to WorkItemDetails via go_router:
   GoRoute(
          path: 'work-item-details/:projectId/:id',
          builder: (context, state) {
            final projectId = state.pathParameters['projectId']!;
            final id = state.pathParameters['id']!;

            return BlocProvider(
              key: ValueKey('$projectId-$id'),
              create: (context) => WorkItemDetailsBloc()
                ..add(
                  WorkItemDetailsStartedEvent(projectId, id),
                ),
              child: WorkItemDetails(
                projectId: projectId,
                id: id,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),

Values of WorkItemDetailsState workItem when I hover over state.workItem in the method you can find below:
affectedGroups =null
assignedToMemberWhenClosed =null
assignedToMemberWhenClosedId =null
assignee =null
attachments =null
code =null
comments =null
createdAt =null
createdBy =null
description =null
dueDate =null
followers =null
hashCode =1579431306
hoursEstimation =null
id =null
other properties null as well...

Multiblocprovider from main.dart:
MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<AttachmentsCubit>(
            lazy: false,
            create: (BuildContext context) => AttachmentsCubit(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<TagsCubit>(
            lazy: false,
            create: (BuildContext context) => TagsCubit(
              projectSettingsCubit: context.read<ProjectSettingsCubit>(),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider<FollowersCubit>(
            lazy: false,
            create: (BuildContext context) => FollowersCubit(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<WorkItemDetailsBloc>(
            lazy: false,
            create: (BuildContext context) => WorkItemDetailsBloc(
              followersCubit: BlocProvider.of<FollowersCubit>(context),
              attachmentsCubit: BlocProvider.of<AttachmentsCubit>(context),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider<WorkItemsBloc>(
            lazy: false,
            create: (BuildContext context) => WorkItemsBloc(
              workItemDetailsBloc: BlocProvider.of<WorkItemDetailsBloc>(context),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp.router(

WorkItemDetailsBloc with cubit subscriptions:
class WorkItemDetailsBloc extends Bloc<WorkItemDetailsEvent, WorkItemDetailsState> {
  final FollowersCubit? followersCubit;
  late StreamSubscription followersCubitSubscription;
  final AttachmentsCubit? attachmentsCubit;
  late StreamSubscription attachmentsCubitSubscription;

  WorkItemDetailsBloc({
    this.followersCubit,
    this.attachmentsCubit,
    WorkItemDetailsRepository? workItemDetailsRepository,
  })  : _workItemDetailsRepository = workItemDetailsRepository ?? locator.get<WorkItemDetailsRepository>(),
        super(
          WorkItemDetailsState.init(),
        ) {
    if (attachmentsCubit != null) {
      attachmentsCubitSubscription = attachmentsCubit!.stream.listen((attachmentsState) {
        if (attachmentsState.status == AttachmentsStatus.success) {
          add(UpdateWorkItemDetailsOnAttachmentsUpdateEvent());
        }
      });
    }

    if (followersCubit != null) {
      followersCubitSubscription = followersCubit!.stream.listen((followerState) {
        if (followerState.status == FollowersStatus.success) {
          add(UpdateWorkItemDetailsOnFollowersUpdateEvent(
            followerState.followers,
          ));
        }
      });
    } 


Bloc methods...
 on<UpdateWorkItemDetailsOnFollowersUpdateEvent>(onUpdateWorkItemDetailsOnFollowersUpdate);
other bloc methods... 
} 

final WorkItemDetailsRepository _workItemDetailsRepository;  

  Future<void> onUpdateWorkItemDetailsOnFollowersUpdate(
    UpdateWorkItemDetailsOnFollowersUpdateEvent event,
    Emitter<WorkItemDetailsState> emit,
  ) async {
    final updatedWorkItem = state.workItem;
    updatedWorkItem.copyWith(followers: event.followers);

    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        workItem: updatedWorkItem,
        status: WorkItemDetailsStatus.success,
      ),
    );
  }

I tried navigating the user to WorkItemDetailsPage without creating a new WorkItemDetailsBloc but I still get the same problem of properties being null.
 GoRoute(
          path: 'work-item-details/:projectId/:id',
          builder: (context, state) {
            final projectId = state.pathParameters['projectId']!;
            final id = state.pathParameters['id']!;

            return WorkItemDetails(
              projectId: projectId,
              id: id,
            );
          },
        ),```

